# Entity Framework 4 and DB2: database generation error

Tags: entity-framework-4, db2

We are using Entity Framework 4 RC on Visual Studio 2010 with DB2 version 9.7.3.4. I also have the VS Add-ins and can see the DB2 database in Server Explorer. I have created a very simple VS console project and it works fine against SQL Server, so I know it is valid. I have references to "IBM.Data.DB2.9.7.3" and "IBM.Data.DB2.Entity" in my project.

In app.config my connnection string is:

```
<add name="ProductContext"  
     providerName="IBM.Data.DB2"  
     connectionString="Database=DB2TEST;User ID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;Server=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;"/>
```

The first statement in my code is a database initializer:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<ProductContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>());
```

During run-time when I reach a line that causes a change to the data context I get the error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked
>   because the database does not contain
>   model metadata.

Since I requested that the database be dropped, this does not seem to be a logical error. Does anyone know what the cause could be?

Comment: Do you have permissions to check existence of database and tables in that database?

Comment: The user is an Administrator of the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to inherit from CreateDatabaseIfNotExists first, which will add the EdmMetadata table to the schema. I believe the error is that EF is saying that it cannot find that table.

So

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<ProductContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ProductContext>());
```

Run it once, then change to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges once the EdmMetadata table exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I did the above, an error is thrown on execution of db.SaveChanges(). The InnerException is: {"ERROR [42704] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0204N  \"DBO.CATEGORIES\" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704\r\n"}. It sounds as though the database exists and the table does not exist. But a new database is not created or persisted. Has anyone had success generating a DB in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the IncludeMetadataConvention like this:`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();` 
To avoid the "dbo" issue, just map all your entities using either DataAnnotation attributes or Fluent mapping:

```
[Table("Product", SchemaName = "MySchema")]
public class Category { //DataAnnotoaion approach

modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Categories", "MySchema"); //Fluent approach
```